# Displaying Power Automate Variable Text in Web Browser via JavaScript (Run JavaScript function on web page)

Tags: javascript, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I am attempting to display a Power Automate Desktop variable's numeric value in a web browser instance using the `Run JavaScript function on web page` action in Power Automate Desktop (PAD). My PAD flow is as follows:

PAD user input via custom form --> Input value feeds into Excel model --> Excel model spits out output value --> Output value is read by PAD (`ExcelData` or `model_output`) --> PAD attempts to display `model_output` in a blank web browser page via JS function (`Run JavaScript function on web page`).

Here is my JS function:

```
function InjectOutput()
{
    var output = "%model_output%";
    document.querySelectorAll('document')[0].value=output;
}
```

This is the Microsoft help link I tried to use - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/how-to/populate-text-fields-click-links-javascript

Here is my entire PAD flow:
[image]
[image]

When running, my blank web browser page does not populate the value of `model_output` and I get a popup that reads "Microsoft Power Automate started debugging this browser."

Thanks for help with the JS function or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by switching to a simpler web page (blank.page) and modifying my code slightly based on selection of the appropriate Selector in the UI elements tab:

```
function InjectOutput()
{
    let output = "%model_output%";
    document.querySelector('textarea').value=output;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).